# Cors not working after AWS S3 settings added. REACT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

I am trying to upload an image file to AWS s3. Am encountring issue with my CORS,

in my Core settings on AWS S3 I have set this:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>Anonymous</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I have tried several other cases where I specified  `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>`, and `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>` and added PUT, DELETE optiosn etc. As well as.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
```

I get this error every time.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://placifulll-realestate.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have read through some AWS S3 documentation none of them really helped to give me the idea what is wrong, as all of these options I have tried.

The HTML is :

```
 <div className="single-file-input">
            <input
              type="file"
              id="user_image"
              name="user_image"
              onChange={this.handleFiles}
            />
            <div>
              Upload a picture<i className="fa fa-upload"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Then the js function is as per below:

```
handleFiles = (e) => {
uploadFile(e.target.files);
```

};

And the utils .js code for REACT:

```
import S3 from "react-aws-s3";

const ID = "";
const SECRET = "";
const BUCKET_NAME = "";
const REGION_NAME = "";

const config = {
  bucketName: BUCKET_NAME,
  /*dirName: 'media', /* optional */
  region: REGION_NAME,
  accessKeyId: ID,
  secretAccessKey: SECRET,
  /*s3Url: 'https:/your-custom-s3-url.com/', /* optional */
};

const ReactS3Client = new S3(config);
/*  Notice that if you don't provide a dirName, the file will be automatically uploaded to the root of your bucket */

/* This is optional */
const newFileName = "test-file";

export const uploadFile = (file) => {
  ReactS3Client.uploadFile(file, newFileName)
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));

};
```

Is there anything else I need to set up?  I am really confused how to set up this.

Comment: I have removed the Keys out of the code of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was a pain! I still have not understood, why the above code haven't worked. I changed the library to react-s3 and this worked, as per the post below. From this, I managed to upload the file to aws s3.

https://medium.com/@rachid1982fsb/upload-images-on-a-react-app-to-aws-s3-bucket-3f3114a683f1